# C# TcpClient PSH, ACk

Tags: c#, tcp, wireshark, tcpclient

Im connecting to a device using TcpClient. Looking at the transmission via Wireshark (after connection is ok), im seeing my request sent to device, then I receive first [ACK], then [PSH,ACK] with the actual data, then apperently I'm sending ACK again. Is this just Wireshark giving details, or are they physical?

If physical then I guess its double amount of traffic. Can I avoid them? If its slowing down my queries I would like them removed. :)

Additional information (if it affects the answer), im sending one package containing aprox 8 bytes of data and receive at max 130 bytes of data, then the query is done until new query. I set the NoDelay flag on TcpClient since this seems to be ok for this scenario according to docs.microsoft, hoping this can speed transmission even more.

```
            await client.GetStream().WriteAsync(tcpPayload, 0, tcpPayload.Length, token);
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            await client.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token);
```

[image: Wireshark transmit records]

Comment: Each packet has a IP header and a TCP header.IP header has a sequence number that starts with sequence 1 and increments by one for every time a new packet is sent for each connection.The sequence number from client to server is different.  There is also a length and the ACK length is zero.When a packet is not ACK 5 seconds later and second duplicate packet is sent with same sequence number.The IP header also has a continuation bit for long messages.So it looks like you sent two messages in the opposite direction first being 8 bytes and second 123 bytes and each was ACK in opposite direction.

Comment: You are not getting two ACKs.  Wireshark is just indicating you will be getting an ACK since you are using TCP and letting you that an ACK is coming.

Comment: If the last comment is confirming one theory that only im only sending one physical request and then receiving one response and Wireshark adds some transmission data to output its all good I guess. :)